# Recover Facebook App. which is removed

Tags: facebook, iphone-sdk-3.0

i had created one application which application id is = 435259419885949 and it was removed by mistake and its affecting my application which is live on the apple store so is there any way to recover my app back ?. i cant get any help for recover back the application.so please help me to sort it out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but once the App is removed or deleted its permanent. You can't go back and recover it. Even when deleting the App same thing is also explicitly stated by Facebook

> If you proceed, this app will be deleted. This operation cannot be undone.